# Proof: Sigma Algebra

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a function and let S be a sigma algebra on Y, that is, S is: 
i) Closed under countable unions 
ii) Closed under complements 
iii) $\emptyset \in S$

Show that $R = ${$f^{-1}(B) : B \in S$} is a sigma algebra on X.

I've got the first two parts of this proof, but I'm not sure how to show that the empty set is in R. Any help would be great.

Please note that the empty set is a subset of a every set, but not necessarily an element of every set. We need to show that it is an element of R.

Comment: Note that $f^{-1}$ "distributes over unions and complements, both finite and infinite. Of course, $f^{-1}[\emptyset] = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What is $f^{-1}(\emptyset)$?

Recall that $f^{-1}(B)=\{ x\in X \mid f(x)\in B\}$.

Comment: I thought about this...but the inverse image of $f^{-1}( \emptyset)$ is not necessarily the empty set. Note that we cannot say whether or not f is bijective is not defined. So we don't know if we have an inverse function available for use. Either way, I can construct a function which assigns x's to the empty set...so the inverse image (or function) is not necessarily the empty set.

Comment: I think it's the case that the notation involved with $f^{-1}(B)$ is what's messing you up.  When they write "$f^{-1}(B)$, they mean the pre-image of $B$ under $f$.  So when we write $f^{-1}(\emptyset)$, we mean $\{x \in X \mid f(x)\in \emptyset\}$.  In this form, the emptiness of $f^{-1}(\emptyset)$ should be immediate.  This is in contrast to the case where $f^{-1}$ is actually a function and $\emptyset$ happens to be an actual member of $Y$.  But that isn't what's happening here.